# Creating a new base CDialogEx derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, mfc, cdialog

I have a lot of `CDialogEx` derived classes that do something like this in `OnInitDialog`:

```
CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::InitialiseResizeIcon(m_bmpResize, m_lblResize, this);
CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::RestoreWindowPosition(_T("PublisherDB"), this, true);
```

Then, I have the following added to each derived dialog class:

```
int CPublishersDatabaseDlg::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDialogEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    // Save Initial window size to m_rcInit
    GetWindowRect(&m_rcInit);

    return 0;
}

void CPublishersDatabaseDlg::OnGetMinMaxInfo(MINMAXINFO* lpMMI)
{
    // Set the minimum window size to initial size.
    lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = m_rcInit.Width();
    lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = m_rcInit.Height();

    CDialogEx::OnGetMinMaxInfo(lpMMI);
}

void CPublishersDatabaseDlg::OnClose()
{
    CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::SaveWindowPosition(_T("PublisherDB"), this);
    CDialogEx::OnClose();
}
```

The only thing that is different for each dialog is the phrase that is used for saving the window position.

I want to have a based `CDialogEx` class that I can inherit from that will perform the above actions. I have looked on SO and seem some questions and creating a `CDialog` class and inheriting from another `CDialog` class. But this class I want to create is more generic. Effectively to be used as a base instead of `CDialogEx`.

Can this be done? Am I over-complicating this?

## Problems

Why I try to create a new class, derived from `CDialogEx`:

[image: Setup]

[image: Result]

[image: Error]

I don't know if it is because it requires a **dialog ID** as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/mfc-add-class-wizard).

> Classes such as `CDialog`, `CFormView`, or `CPropertyPage`, which require a **dialog ID**.

So I can't work out the correct way to create a base CDialogEx class for use in all my other dialog classes.

## Update

I created this code and it tells me that `CResizingDialog` is not a class or a namespace:

```
#include "ResizingDialog.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CResizingDialog, CDialogEx)

CResizingDialog::CResizingDialog(const CString& strWindowID, UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd* pParent = nullptr)
    : m_strWindowID(strWindowID), CDialogEx(nIDTemplate, pParent)
{

}

CResizingDialog::~CResizingDialog()
{
}

void CResizingDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CResizingDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_GETMINMAXINFO()
    ON_WM_CLOSE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


int CResizingDialog::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDialogEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    // Save Initial window size to m_rcInit
    GetWindowRect(&m_rcInit);

    return 0;
}


void CResizingDialog::OnGetMinMaxInfo(MINMAXINFO* lpMMI)
{
    // Set the minimum window size to initial size.
    lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = m_rcInit.Width();
    lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = m_rcInit.Height();

    CDialogEx::OnGetMinMaxInfo(lpMMI);
}


void CResizingDialog::OnClose()
{
    SaveWindowPosition(m_strWindowID, this);

    CDialogEx::OnClose();
}
```

Comment: You want to specialize your dialog base class. C++ inheritance is the standard solution to that problem. Just create your dialog base class, derived from `CDialogEx`, provide a c'tor with the same arguments as `CDialogEx`' plus your string identifier. Add a `const CString&` member to that base, and initialize it from your c'tor's initializer list, just like the base. Essentially something like `CDialogBase::CDialogBase(const CString& phrase, UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd* pParent=NULL) : m_phrase(phrase), CDialogEx(nIDTemplate, pParent) {}`.

Comment: @IInspectable Please see updated question.

Comment: @IInspectable Added some more information.

Comment: Just create your `CDialogEx` specialization from scratch, without using the (often broken) Wizard. It's better for the learning experience anyway.

Comment: @zett42 I prefer to learn from a good tutorial if I am doing something by scratch, as opposed to blindly trying. I often find if they are not created correctly with teh classwizard that all the messages don't show in the properties as it doesn't realise what type of object it is.

Comment: @zett42 Working on it

Comment: @zett42 Hit a snag, please see updated question.

Comment: `#include <afxdialogex.h>` on stdafx.h

Comment: @sergiol That is already included in the `stdafx.h` file.

Comment: I had to `#include` the `stdafx.h` file first.

Comment: You need to `#include "ResizingDialog.h"` in every other file using it!

Comment: That's just how precompiled headers work. Everything ahead of the `#include <stdafx.h>` directive is ignored, that's why you get the error, that the symbol is not a class. If you want to prevent such errors, you can use the [/FI (Name Forced Include File)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fi-name-forced-include-file) compiler option, and not ever think about your precompiled header anymore. Well, until things do go wrong again.

Comment: @IInspectable OK, new switch to learn about. But in my project not all source files use precompiled headers. Each file is stated as such. Will using this switch affect them? And if I use it, is it `/FI[stdafx.h]`?

Comment: I don't know the exact format of the compiler option, but you could use Visual Studio's project settings dialog (C/C++ -> Advanced -> Forced Include File) to enable it (and inspect the command line in case you are interested). I believe you can enable the option per project as well as on a per compilation unit basis. Anyway, I hardly ever use it anyway. Only exception is when I have to compile 3rd party code I cannot modify, but still want to continue using precompiled headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments encouraging me to try to create the class manually, I have it working:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "ResizingDialog.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CResizingDialog, CDialogEx)

CResizingDialog::CResizingDialog(const CString& strWindowID, UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd* pParent /* nullptr */, bool bOnlyStorePosition /* false */)
    : m_strWindowID(strWindowID),
      m_bOnlyStorePosition(bOnlyStorePosition), CDialogEx(nIDTemplate, pParent)
{

}

CResizingDialog::~CResizingDialog()
{
}

void CResizingDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CResizingDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_GETMINMAXINFO()
    ON_WM_CLOSE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

int CResizingDialog::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDialogEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    // Save Initial window size to m_rcInit
    GetWindowRect(&m_rcInit);

    return 0;
}

void CResizingDialog::OnGetMinMaxInfo(MINMAXINFO* lpMMI)
{
    // Set the minimum window size to initial size.
    lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = m_rcInit.Width();
    lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = m_rcInit.Height();

    CDialogEx::OnGetMinMaxInfo(lpMMI);
}

void CResizingDialog::OnClose()
{
    SaveWindowPosition(m_strWindowID, this);

    CDialogEx::OnClose();
}

void CResizingDialog::OnOK()
{
    SaveWindowPosition();
    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}

BOOL CResizingDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    if(!m_bOnlyStorePosition)
        InitialiseResizeIcon(m_bmpResize, m_lblResize, this);

    RestoreWindowPosition(m_strWindowID, this, true);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

I decided to duplicate the methods that were in the app class into this new dialog class instead. Eventually they can be removed from the app class. The only thing I also had to do was `#include` my resource file because the image needs to know the value of the resource ID.

This is the `ResizingDialog.h` header:

```
#pragma once
#include <afxwin.h>

class CResizingDialog : public CDialogEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CResizingDialog)

public:
    CResizingDialog(const CString& phrase, UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd* pParent = nullptr, bool bOnlyStorePosition = false); // Constructor
    virtual ~CResizingDialog(); // Destructor

protected:
    void OnOK() override;
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX) override;    // DDX/DDV support
    void SaveWindowPosition(void) { SaveWindowPosition(m_strWindowID, this); }

public:
    BOOL OnInitDialog() override;
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    afx_msg void OnGetMinMaxInfo(MINMAXINFO* lpMMI);
    afx_msg void OnClose();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

private:
    CBitmap m_bmpResize;
    CStatic m_lblResize;
    CRect m_rcInit;
    CString m_strWindowID;
    bool m_bOnlyStorePosition;

    void RestoreWindowPosition(CString strWindow, CWnd* pWindow, bool bOverrideState = false);
    void SaveWindowPosition(CString strWindow, CWnd* pWindow);
    void InitialiseResizeIcon(CBitmap& rBmpResize, CStatic& rLblResize, CWnd* pDialog);
};
```

The actual functions `SaveWindowPosition`, `RestoreWindowPosition` and `InitialiseResizeIcon` are not shown here as they don't directly relate to the issue.

Comment: You should also include the header file.

Comment: @zett42 What header?

Comment: "ResizingDialog.h". Someone who reads this answer to learn how to inherit from `CDialogEx` would surely need this information.

Comment: @zett42 That is line three in my code. Surely it is common sense if they use this class to derive from in another class that they include the header? #confused :)

Comment: I meant to include the content of "ResizingDialog.h" in the answer, not the `#include` line.

Comment: @zett42 Ah, right. I have added it. Note that I do not understand why I have to specify my fourth paramater `bOnlyStorePosition` since it defaults to `false`. But if I do not specify it the compiler complains. That is another issue.

Comment: In your header the 4th c'tor parameter doesn't have a default defined.

Comment: @zett42 OK, I revised my answer to have the updated code. I do specify a default.

Comment: Oops, you have updated the code of the .cpp, not the .h file.

Comment: I just refreshed the page, it's not. The declarations in .h and .cpp file must be swapped.

Comment: @zett42 What a muppet. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: You don't need `OnCreate`. You can put the window initialization in `OnInitDialog` - The constructor and destructor have to be `public`. Members like `OnInitDialog` should be `protected` because you don't need to call them from outside, it doesn't really matter though...

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Where does `OnInitDialog` fit in relation to `OnGetMinMaxInfo`?

Comment: `OnGetMinMaxInfo` is called before `OnInitDialog` and `OnCreate`. So `m_rcInit` is not properly initialized, it initially mis-informs the dialog that the minimum size is zero, but it's not a problem. You can initialize `m_rcInit` in constructor to set it to zero, to make it clear.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Then I don't get it. `OnGetMinMaxInfo` is supposed to state the minimum size of the dialog. This always works for me the way I have it.

Comment: You asked about the relation `OnGetMinMaxInfo` to `OnInitDialog`. It's called once before `OnInitDialog`. It's called again whenever you resize, by that time `m_rcInit` is set and it works as expected.